# go tutorial: what is the & doing in this line?

Tags: go

I am doing the go tutorial and I had a question about this exercise... https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/5

I have only briefly worked with pointers and addresses in rudimentary C code before. My understanding is that the line `p  = &Vertex{1, 2} // has type *Vertex` is pointing a new variable `p` to the address of `Vertex`.

Wouldn't this then be redefining the definition of the `struct` to set `X, Y int = 1, 2`

Here is the full code from the tutorial:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Vertex struct {
    X, Y int
}

var (
    v1 = Vertex{1, 2}  // has type Vertex
    v2 = Vertex{X: 1}  // Y:0 is implicit
    v3 = Vertex{}      // X:0 and Y:0
    p  = &Vertex{1, 2} // has type *Vertex
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(v1, p, v2, v3)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`var p = &Vertex{1, 2}` does the following:

- Creates an anonymous variable of type `Vertex` with the values 1 for
  `x` and 2 for `y`
- Creates a variable `p` of type `*Vertex` (pointer
  to `Vertex`)
- Sets `p` to point to the anonymous variable.

It doesn't affect the definition of the type.

Comment: ok I was missing the anonymous variable part. Out of curiosity, is there any way to get to this anonymous variable? What is the practical application of doing this?

Comment: You can only access it through the pointer. You'll often see this done when the situation calls for a pointer to a particular type. For example, a package might define a `New()` function that returns a pointer to to an initialized instance of a type. That might be done with something like `return &MyType{field1: val1, field2: val2}`.

Comment: More info about the usage I referred to: https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#composite_literals